# Java 8: change type of entries return Map

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I got the follwoing question: 
I have a `Map<?,?>` and I parse it from an PList file, simplified like:

```
Map<String, String> m  = (Map<String, String>) getMap();
```

The `getMap()` method just reads the file (.plist).
I want to parse all the values to String, but unfortunately the Map contains Integers, causing an error later in the process. 
So I wanted to write a method using the filter to convert everything to String:

My approach is:

```
m.entrySet().stream()
    .map(e -> e.getValue())
    .filter(e -> e instanceof Integer)
    .map(e -> String.valueOf(e))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.keys(), e -> e.getValue()));
```

The problem is, that the collect at the end is not working, how can I fix this? 
The result should be a map again.

Thank you a lot!

Comment: You should not use filter. With this you will get only integer values

Comment: @hnefatl, see it, I fixed it but it doesn't solve the issue:
`Multiple markers at this line
 - Incompatible conditional operand types String and Integer
 - Cannot infer type argument(s) for <R, A> collect(Collector<? super 
  T,A,R>)`

Comment: @pvpkiran do you have a suitable solution for this issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're misunderstanding how [`Collectors.toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-) works - it takes two functions, one that given an entry produces a new key, and one that given an entry produce a new value. Each entry in the map then has both of these functions applied to it and the resulting key/value for that single element are used to construct the new entry in the new map.

Also, by mapping each entry to just the value, you lose the association between keys and values, which means you can't reconstruct the map correctly.

A corrected version would be:

```
Map<String, String> n;
n = m.entrySet()
     .stream()
     .filter(e -> e.getValue() instanceof Integer)
     .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(),
                               e -> String.valueOf(e.getValue())));
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a few errors in your code.

First, as you are mapping each entry to its value, you are losing the keys.

Then, when you filter, you are keeping only `Integer` values in the stream, which will yield an incomplete map.

Finally, in `Collectors.toMap` you are using `e.keys()` and `e.getValue`, which are incorrect, because `e.keys()` is not a method of neither `Map.Entry` nor `String`, and because you'd need to use `e.getValue()` instead of `e.getValue`.

The code should be as follows:

```
m.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
    e -> e.getKey(), 
    e -> e.getValue() instanceof Integer ?
        String.valueOf(e.getValue()) : 
        e.getValue()));
```

Comment: is it just me here that whenever I see `e.getValue()` called 3 times, I panic? :) still pus one

Comment: @Eugene yes, it was this vs a lambda with body... Ughh

Answer (score 2):

The `replaceAll` method is probably more suitable for this. It can be used like:

```
m.replaceAll((k, v) -> String.valueOf(v));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Map<String, String> m2 = m.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> Objects.toString(e.getKey()),
                              e -> Objects.toString(e.getValue())));
```

This will turn both key and value into strings by toString. A null (value) will be turned into "null".